# unable to find Hp laserjet mfp 226dn printer driver for CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos, printer, hp

I am unable to find Hp laserjet mfp 226dn printer driver for CentOS7. Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

According to [these HPLIP release notes from HP](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/release_notes), that printer model is supported in HPLIP version 3.14.10 and newer. Looks like [CentOS 7.x includes HPLIP 3.15.9](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/hplip-3.15.9-5.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) so you should just run `yum install hplip` to install the driver.

After installing HPLIP, you can run `hp-probe -busb` if the printer is connected with USB, or `hp-probe -bnet` if a network connection is used. (You might need to use `hp-probe -bnet -mmdns` in some cases.) It should display the "Device URI" that you can use with CUPS to configure the printing queue for the printer. For scanning, see `man hp-scan` and `man hp-makecopies`.

If the version of HPLIP that's included in RHEL/CentOS 7.x causes problems for you, you can download HPLIP version 3.22.2 (at the time of this writing) intended for RHEL 7 here: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip

It should be installable to CentOS 7.

According to [these specifications from HP](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-laserjet-pro-mfp-m226-series/6778492/model/6778498/document/c04371475) your printer supports AirPrint, which means CUPS should be able to automatically discover your printer in the network if it's in the same network segment as your CentOS 7 system. Also, it seems to use PCL 5 printing language, so you might be able to use generic PCL 5 drivers if HPLIP does not work for you for some reason.